# How to calculate response time in selenium using vb.net

Tags: javascript, vb.net, selenium, load, automated-tests

I need to write a automated test to calculate average response time for a screen to respond. I am using selenium and VB.net. Please guide how to calculate it. as waitforpage() only let you specify a maximum period of time for waiting. How I can actually get the time it took to load.

Kind regards
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, I'd share you approach that I used but only in java. Hope you'll be able somehow adopt it ot vb.net.

```
public class CodeTimingMeasurement extends BaseSeleniumTest {
    @Test
    public void rmsHomeTiming() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        doLogout();
        locatorFindingHandling("login.logininput", "login.admin.login");

        locatorFindingHandling("login.passinput", "login.admin.pass");
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        locatorFindingHandling("login.loginbutton");


        loaderInficatorsDisappear("rms.loadingwindow");


        fluentWait(By.cssSelector(propertyKeysLoader("rms.home.timeoffs.gearicon")));
        fluentWait(By.cssSelector(propertyKeysLoader("rms.home.logout")));
        fluentWait(By.cssSelector(propertyKeysLoader("home.timeoffs.own")));

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
        System.out.println("Totaltime: " + totalTime + " milliseconds");

    }
}
```

the idea is following: 
you press login button or any other element causign page load. Then you start timer. Then you select a set of elements which are supposed to be displayed on the page. And using fluentWait mechanism you wait till they appear. And then timer is supposed to be stopped.

fluent wait [info](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html)
fluent wait method code:

```
 public WebElement fluentWait(final By locator){
        Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
//                .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

        WebElement foo = wait.until(
                new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
                    public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                        return driver.findElement(locator);
                    }
                }
        );
        return  foo;              }     ;
```

Hope somthning comes clear to you)